# Why does conversion from SqlDecimal to Decimal throw an overflow exception because of trailing zeroes?

Tags: .net, sql-server, .net-core, type-conversion, decimal

It is well known (see e.g. [What is a good mapping of .NET decimal to SQL Server decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152439/) or [.NET Decimal = what in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230105/)) that **no** choice for `precision,scale` can make the SQL Server type `decimal(precision, scale)` contain all possible values for a .NET (or .NET Core) `System.Decimal`. Because one `System.Decimal` value can have up to 28 digits after the decimal point, while another `System.Decimal` can have up to 29 digits in its integral part (portion to the left of the decimal point), and clearly 28+29 exceeds 38, the maximal possible `precision` in SQL Sever `decimal`.

One somewhat **natural choice** for `precision,scale` is then `38,28`, because then for sure no precision is ever lost (28 digits *after* the point), and so we take the greatest range possible with that. With `decimal(38, 28)`, the greatest magnitude is then `10**10` (10 billion) because we still have up to ten digits for the integral parts; this is sufficient for our purpose.

We use the type [`System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes.sqldecimal) as an intermediate. The problem is this type handles conversions extremely poorly.

Consider this simple example (C#):

```cs
var sd = SqlDecimal.ConvertToPrecScale(10.4m, precision: 38, scale: 28);
Console.WriteLine(sd.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(sd.Value);  // throws
```

or equivalently in PowerShell if you prefer that:

```bsh
$sd = [System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal]::ConvertToPrecScale(10.4d, 38, 28)
$sd
$sd.ToString()
[decimal]$sd  # throws
```

What this does, is to take a simple .NET `System.Decimal`, namely `10.4`, and convert it into an `SqlDecimal` with precision 38 and scale 28 (first line). This seems to go OK when you inspect the resulting struct value (middle line(s)). But once you try to convert it back (round-trip) to a `System.Decimal` (last line), instead of getting your `10.4` back, you get an `OverflowException` with message `"Conversion overflows."` thrown at you.

I know `SqlDecimal` is a fixed-point type, and this value of it can be thought of as:

```
10.4000000000000000000000000000
```

with two digits to the left of the point, and twenty-eight digits to the right, but since the last twenty-seven of them are zeroes, should the conversion to `System.Decimal` not be allowed?

*My questions:*

Why was `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal` (in particular its conversion to `System.Decimal`) designed this way?

Does this not make `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal` useless for converting a value retrieved from the database into a usual .NET value? The analogous problem/bug occurs for other `scale`s of course.

Is there a better way to go from `SqlDecimal` to `Decimal`?

Comment: There is a related question [OverflowException when converting SqlDecimal to Decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37449806/) where (in the question itself) there is an ugly extension method that counts the number of trailing zeroes in the string representation of the `SqlDecimal`, then changes the precision and scale of the `SqlDecimal` to something minimal. _Then_ the resulting `SqlDecimal` can be converted to `System.Decimal` by getting its `.Value` property.

Comment: Were you ever able to consistently use`System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal` in your project? @jeppe-stig-nielsen

Comment: @eRunner No. I just verified that with [the .NET 8 version of the type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes.sqldecimal?view=net-8.0), my example from the question still throws.